# Obtener el valor ingresado dentro de un div

Tags: reactjs, div, jsx, contentvalues

Tengo tres contenedores en los cuales estoy insertando botones con diferentes nombres, necesito obtener el nombre de cada boton insertado en cada contenedor y que todo este dentro de un array por ejemplo :

Contenedor Filas: inserte el btn empresa
Contenedor Columnas: inserte el btn soles
Contenedor Valores: inserte el btn fecha

El array deberia ser asi: ['empresa', 'soles', 'fecha']

Mi pregunta es: como puedo saber el nombre de cada botón que inserte en cada contenedor, sin tener que dar click en el contenedor ni en el botón que estoy insertando.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../assets/styles/Container.css";
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";
import ButtonApp from "./ButtonApp";
import { getData } from "../services/api_aralsoft";

const Container = () => {
  
  const [row, setRow] = useState([]);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bottomContainer">
        <section className="itemsSelected">
          <div className="containerVertical">
            <div className="containerR">
              Filas
              <ReactSortable list={row} setList={setRow} group="selectedButton">
                {!row
                  ? "Cargando..."
                  : row.map((item, index) => (
                      <button className="btnSelect" key={index}>
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    ))}
              </ReactSortable>
            </div>
          </div>
          <article className="container_col_val">
            <div className="containerHorizontal">
              <div className="containerR">
                Columnas
                <ReactSortable
                  list={column}
                  setList={setColumn}
                  group="selectedButton"
                >
                  {!column
                    ? "Cargando..."
                    : column.map((item, index) => (
                        <button className="btnSelect" key={index}>
                          {item}
                        </button>
                      ))}
                </ReactSortable>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="containerHorizontal">
              <div className="containerR">
                Valores
                <ReactSortable
                  list={values}
                  setList={setValues}
                  group="selectedButton"
                >
                  {!values
                    ? "Cargando..."
                    : values.map((item, index) => (
                        <button className="btnSelect" key={index}>
                          {item}
                        </button>
                      ))}
                </ReactSortable>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </section>
        <section>
          <ButtonApp name="Generar Reporte" />
        </section>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con el `nombre del botón`?

Comment: @Sr1871 cada boton tiene un nombre por ejemplo 'empresa', 'cantidad', etc.  cuando inserto cualquiera de esos botones dentro de un contenedor, necesito saber cual es el boton que estoy insertando, osea obtener el nombre de ese boton insertado dentro del contenedor. ME explico?

Comment: Pero te refieres al texto del botón, es decir a la linea de `{item}`?

Comment: Cual es la finalidad de conocer sus nombres? Que harás con esa información? Mostrar ese dato en el botón? Cuál es la estructura de filas, columnas y value?

Comment: @GmrYael la finalidad al saber cual es el boton que estoy insertando dentro del contenedor es luego buscar en una api los valores que tenga dicho boton y pintarlos en una tabla. Pero para eso necesito saber cual es el boton que fue insertando, porque son varios y no tienen los mismos valores.

Comment: Entonces por lo que entiendo el flujo de tu aplicación es: almacenar dentro un botón el nombre(valor utilizado para consultar el API) y que al presionar sobre este botón te muestre los datos filtrado por ese valor, y que el evento onClick de dicho botón te haga la petición tomando en cuenta el valor del botón que presiones?

Comment: @GmrYael si eso  quiero.

Comment: Me lo suponía, creo que eso nos da una mejor perspectiva y recibirás más respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es usar la propiedad de [ref callback](https://elfi-y.medium.com/react-callback-refs-a-4bd2da317269) que ofrece react para llamar un método que inserte en tu array el nombre que recibe del componente que se cargo.

Seria algo asi:

```javascript
let botones = []

const add_to_array = (button) => {
   botones.push(button.key)
   setRow(botones)
}

{!row
  ? "Cargando..."
  : row.map((item, index) => (
      <button className="btnSelect" key={index} ref={(button) => add_to_array(button)}>
        {item}
      </button>
    ))}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Cloud89 cambie el key por textContent quedando algo asi ``` let botones = [];

  const add_to_array = (button) => {
    //console.log(button);
    const x = botones.push(button.textContent);
    console.log("el push y el text content ", x);
    //setRow(botones);
    console.log("agregando botones al array vacio", botones);
  };   ```  funciona... si se agregan los botones al array justo lo que necesito pero me genera este error ahora : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

Comment: @Naidamag es normal, solo agrega una condicional para verificar que tu valor no sea null if botto != null {*/Poner tu lógica para agregar elemento al array/*}.  Porque lo que esta pasando es que en las primeras pasadas tu aplicación no renderiza toda via el componente botón por lo que al cargar las primeras veces retornara un valor nulo, pero condicionando con un if te saltas el problema

Comment: Tu método podría quedar así  `const add_to_array = (button) => {
   button ? botones.push(button.key) : null
   setRow(botones)
}`

Comment: @Cloud89 ahora mira lo que me sale  Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: @Naidamag Se cicla tu aplicación. Porque? Tu código genera tus componentes los cuales reaccionan al estado "row", luego se crea el componente BUTTON, que pasa cuando se crea este componente? el estado "row" es alterado, osease, que tu componente se creara desde 0 otra vez, y pasara lo mismo una y otra y otra vez, lo que tendrás que hacer es cambiar la logica de tu codigo, tal vez guardar tu arreglo de nombres en una variable y no en un estado, o tenerla en un estado aparte y cargar tu arreglo solo cuando se usen los botones, etc.

Comment: Una regla importante en React es no mutar estados directamente en la renderización de un componente el problema aquí es que a diferencia de propiedades como onClick, ref sera disparada en cuanto el componente sea montado por lo que es preferible que este no interactue directamente con un estado

Comment: @Cloud89 Enonces segun lo que entiendo es mejor guardar el valor de botones en una variable nueva Ej const result = botones; Para que asi tenga en esta variable mi array con los botones seleccionados. Es correcto?

Comment: @Naidamag en este caso si, porque ref se dispara cuando se renderiza el componente, y como te digo, uno no debe mutar un estado al renderizar un componente (lo que se esta haciendo en este caso), por lo que seria mejor que lo guardes en un arreglo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140046/discussion-between-naidamag-and-cloud89).